# How to correlate 2D mask with noisy image?

Tags: image, matlab, 2d, correlation, points

I have a matrix  'A' with two columns which contains  2D points ( coordinates 'x' and 'y'). These points earlier were projected onto the plane from 3d cloud, so they create a 2d shape of some object.
For the second I have a noisy image 'B'(4k x 4k matrix) with similar (but translated and scaled) shape. What I want to do is to correlate points from matrix 'A' and use them as a binary mask for the object on the image 'B'. Currently i dont have a slightest idea how to do it.
Thanks for all help.

Comment: Are the `(x,y)` pairs you have randomly scattered or on some non-mesh grid? If so, the first thing I would do is generate a version of this shape on a regularly spaced meshed grid, which I am assuming is the type of grid `B` is on. Maybe use tri-scattered interpolation. You might have to threshold the result to get back to a binary image; I have no idea if that's an issue. If so, maybe you can just use nearest neighbor or something. Once you have the two images on the same type of grid, you can easily correlate them.

Comment: The situation had changed a little. For now I have binary map of object 300x500 'A', and 4000x4000 noisy image with depicted object('B'). The problem is that they have different sizes  both of their planes and the objects depicted on them ). Moreover the object on 'A' plane is translated agianst that on the image 'B'. Do you now the simpest solution how can I correlate these images?

Comment: The translation won't bother the correlation (the correlation will peak where the two line up) but the different sizes will (or if one is rotated w.r.t. the other). If the difference in sizes (or rotation) is unknown, I think you'll have to move beyond correlation and into more nuanced pattern recognition.

Answer (score 0):

Following off of what AnonSubmitter85 suggested with the pattern recognition method, something like a SIFT (Scale Invariant Feature Transformation) detector might be helpful in the case of the scaled and rotated object. Similarly, matlab has a set of functions that do SURF (Speeded Up Robust Features) detection:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/find-image-rotation-and-scale-using-automated-feature-matching.html

Hopefully this can stimulate some new ideas.